# Parmenides and deductions about existence

Tags: deduction, greeks

I am beginner in philosophy and have some problem following this paragraph:

"From the premise that something exists (“It is”), Parmenides deduces that it cannot also not exist (“It is not”), as this would involve a logical contradiction. It follows therefore that a state of nothing existing is impossible—there can be no void. Something cannot then come from nothing, and so must always have existed in some form. "

I have two questions from above:

- What I can't follow is how did he deduce above that "nothing existing" is impossible? Let's assume it exists. Then based on above it had to imply that it would not be possible for nothing *to not exist right*? But still I don't see how the conclusion was made that nothing existing is impossible.
- Finally in the last sentence, how does he deduce that "Something cannot then come from nothing"? It is written in a way like it follows from previous paragraph, but how?

Comment: Bear in mind that apart from the issue of understanding what Parmenides meant, his argument is committing the age-old fallacy of using 'nothing' as a noun, i.e. as the name of a thing, when it is really a quantifier. Lewis Carroll has some fun with the word 'nobody' in the same vein, in this quote from Alice Through the Looking Glass. https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/465132-who-did-you-pass-on-the-road-the-king-went

Answer (score 1):

Parmenides starts with the basic premise that "something exists" or "It is." This is an axiomatic starting point - we intuit that there must be some kind of existence or being. ===>

Parmenides deduces that "nothing exists" or "It is not" must be impossible. Because if nothing existed, then there would be nothing for something to exist. But we already said that something exists, so nothing cannot exist. ===>

Therefore, a state of complete nothingness or non-being cannot obtain. For Parmenides, nothingness is inconceivable - for there to be nothing, there would have to be something (i.e. nothingness itself). But we have rejected nothingness. ===>

This means that whatever exists must always have existed in some form. It could not have arisen from a prior state of nothingness, because such a state is impossible. ===>

For something to come from nothing, there would first have to be a nothing for that something to arise from. But Parmenides argued that nothingness or non-being is inconceivable. There must always have been some form of being. ===>

Parmenides concludes that whatever exists must be eternal and ungenerated. It could not have come into being from a void, because a void cannot exist. It must have always existed in some form!

Answer (score 0):

1. **Why is "nothing existing" impossible according to Parmenides?**

   Parmenides argues that "it is" (meaning something exists) and "it is not" (meaning something does not exist) cannot both be true at the same time for the same object, as this would create a logical contradiction.

   If we were to consider "nothing" as existing, it would imply that "nothing" is "something" because it exists, and this contradicts the very definition of "nothing." Hence, Parmenides concludes that a state of "nothing existing" is impossible. In simpler terms, to even speak of "nothing" gives it a form of existence, thus it cannot truly be "nothing."
2. **Why does Parmenides argue that "something cannot then come from nothing"?**

   This follows from his previous point. If a state of "nothing existing" is impossible, then there was never a time when "nothing" existed. Therefore, "something" must have always existed in some form.

   If "nothing" ever existed, then "something" would have had to come from "nothing," but Parmenides rejects this as impossible based on his previous argument. Therefore, Parmenides concludes that something must always have existed and cannot have come from nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have one question. 'If "nothing" ever existed, then "something" would have had to come from "nothing," but Parmenides rejects this as impossible based on his previous argument' -- when you say Parmenides rejects this in his previous argument, do you mean Parmenides said that "something" could not come from "nothing" or he said that we can't have "nothing" in the first place? It seems it is the latter no?

Answer (score 0):

Parmenidis, starts with two principles: The *being* ("όν") exists and it is not possible that it does not exist, and the "non-*being*" does not exist as it is *nessesary* that it does not exist. The first is analyzed in his texts and for the second he says that we cannot know the *being* or express it; but he gives us a hint, see (1).

1. Parmenidis, considers cognition ("νοείν") the same with the *being* - "It is" ("όν"). Therefore, something that does not exist (non-*being*) cannot be conceived.
2. Parmenidis, considers the *being* as an absolute and continuous presence. Therefore "creation" does not exist: if we accept creation, then we should accept that the *being* was created from the non-*being*, ie. from something that didn't exist.